# Função javascript não executa

Tags: javascript, c#

Tenho uma verificação em c# que caso ela seja verdadeira, executa a seguinte função em javascript:

```
@{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TipoPecaController.MsgExcluir))
    {
        if (TipoPecaController.MsgExcluir == "3")
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function MensagemErro() {
                    debugger;
                    try {
                        alertify.alert("Existem itens utilizando este Tipo de Peça.", function () {
                            alertify.message('OK');
                        });
                    } catch (err) {
                        debugger
                    }
                    try {
                        alertify.error("Código e GrupoProduto já existente");
                    } catch (err) {
                        debugger;
                    }
                }
                @TipoPecaController.MsgExcluir = "";
            </script>
        }
    }
}
```

Mas mesmo que a verificação seja verdadeira, o código em javascript não é executado

Comment: isso está numa pagina `.cshtml`, MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `.ready()`, vai realizar a ação assim que terminar de carregar a página, contando que você usa `JQuery` por estar com códigos `.Net`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('Teste')
    })
</script>
```

Ou você pode tentar sem atribuir um nome à sua função usando apenas `Javascript` puro:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() 
    {
      console.log('Teste')
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente utilizar o ScriptManager

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourUniqueScriptKey", "alert('This pops up');", true);
```

Mais detalhes: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx